# Ceres is spherical, Vesta isn't – is it the largest non-spherical solid body in the solar system?

Tags: asteroids, planetary-formation

I was showing a recent video about Ceres to a friend and we looked up asteroids. Ceres has attained a fairly spherical shape, but Vesta still has a way to go. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_Vesta#Physical_characteristics):

> Vesta's shape is close to a gravitationally relaxed oblate spheroid, but the large concavity and protrusion at the southern pole (see 'Surface features' below) combined with a mass less than $5×10^{20}$ kg precluded Vesta from automatically being considered a dwarf planet under International Astronomical Union (IAU) Resolution XXVI 5.

I don't know the proper term to use here. Perhaps it is "hydrostatically relaxed" or something similar – I'm looking for the term that would suggest a body has reached a fairly round shape without major excursions, under the influence of its own gravity.

I think Ceres meets this criterion, and Vesta doesn't. Is Vesta the largest such body (by dimension or volume, not sure which would be the most reasonable measure)?

Comment: A related and I thought it was a fun read, at least the top answer:   https://www.quora.com/How-and-why-are-planets-spherical-What-makes-them-round#!n=96

Comment: @userLTK that is absolutely fascinating! I've asked a [follow-up question](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19202/7982). Thank you for that!

Comment: I couldn't find tags for planetoid or planetessimal, would something like these be appropriate now?

Comment: @Chirlu I've moved the sentence you proposed deleting into a comment, then accepted your edit. It should have been a comment from the beginning, however next time consider moving rather than simply discarding helpful suggestions.

Comment: @uhoh: OK, but I thought after more than one year, it's not going to happen anyway. ;-) In any case, as it is now, it is properly associated with your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the asteroids 4 Vesta is the largest non-spherical object in the Solar system. But far out there in the Kuiper Belt is 136108 Haumea, and maybe yet undiscovered objects, that are very elongated. Haumea is 1,960 × 1,518 × 996 km. That's larger than the 960 km diameter Ceres and hardly spherical with 2:1 proportions. Its fast rotation and composition of malleable volatiles makes this possible. Maybe Haumea is "hydrostatically relaxed" without being spherical?

Haumea images below from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haumea).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! We should probably iron out the remaining question still. I think for a relaxed body it would be spherical if not rotating much or an oblate spheroid if rotating - either way the surface would have reached equilibrium. I don't think a tri-axial ellipsoid is the minimum energy shape. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAU_definition_of_planet#First_draft_proposal) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_planet).

Comment: Wow! It seems the triaxial ellipsoid [certainly **can be**](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19207/7982) the minimum energy solution (or at least close to it). Stackexchange to the rescue!

Comment: [Dunham et al. (2019)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019ApJ...877...41D/abstract) argue that Haumea's triaxial shape is indeed consistent with hydrostatic equilibrium.

Answer (score 2):

To add to LocalFluff's answer, the largest known clearly irregular body is the [asteroid Juno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_Juno) (mean diameter: 246.6 km / 153.2 mi) in the main belt. However, celestial bodies can be spherical by chance, while far from hydrostatic equilibrium, like in case of Martian moon Phobos. A better way to distinguish asteroids from planets is by interior differentiation. Differentiated bodies are per se somewhat spheroidal. And if we take 'overcoming rigid body forces' literally, even some IAU-recognized planets aren't in hydrostatic equilibrium anyway.